# when i user picasso library then message show me like This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc

Tags: android, shared-libraries, javadoc, picasso

I want to use picasso library for image view. I copy in my lib folder picasso's jar file and then build path.

But when I use in java file and I put mouse over Picosso then message show me like. This element has no attached source and the Javadoc could not be found in the attached Javadoc.

[image]

Can anyone help me for solve error.

Comment: is it giving error...?

Comment: check your mypath... and paste your logs also//

Comment: Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).into(your_image_view);

Comment: now its solve. i need to use old jar file and then it was work

Comment: ok... glad to see it works...